# Php quiz website is not carrying over session variables

Tags: php, xml, session

I have a php file and an xml file. The php is supposed to parse the xml into a quiz but whenever i click submit query to enter my answer choice, the session variables dont carry over. The page is supposed to refresh and give another question to the quiz.
Is this correct usage of php?

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

    session_start(); $_SESSION['qcorrect']; $_SESSION['quizno']; $_SESSION['qvar'] = 0;
    if (!isset($_SESSION['quizno'])){
        $_SESSION['quizno'] = 0;

    }
    if (!isset($_SESSION['qcorrect'])){
        $_SESSION['qcorrect'] = 0;
    }

    ?>
    <html>

    <head>
    <style>
    h1 { text-align:center; }
    p  { text-align:center; }

    </style>

     <title> Memequiz.net </title>

    </head>

        <body>

        <h1>Memequiz.net</h1>



        <div id = "image"  style = width:"500px" align = "middle">

    <?php   


            $xml = simplexml_load_file('firsquiz.xml');


            $question = ($xml -> question[$_SESSION['quizno']] -> ask);
            $correctans = ($xml -> question[$_SESSION['quizno']] -> correctanswer);
            $answer0 = ($xml -> question[$_SESSION['quizno']] -> answers -> answer[$_SESSION['qvar']] -> text);
            $answer1 = ($xml -> question[$_SESSION['quizno']] -> answers -> answer[$_SESSION['qvar']+1] -> text);
            $answer2 = ($xml -> question[$_SESSION['quizno']] -> answers -> answer[$_SESSION['qvar']+2] -> text);
            $answer3 = ($xml -> question[$_SESSION['quizno']] -> answers -> answer[$_SESSION['qvar']+3] -> text);

            echo "<img src = \"".$xml -> question[$_SESSION['quizno']] -> picture."\" alt = \"Meme\" width = \"400\" height = \"350\">";
            echo "<p><br>Question ".$_SESSION['quizno']."<p>Number Correct: ".$_SESSION['qcorrect']."</p><p>".$question."<br></p>";




            echo "<form action = \"\" method = \"get\">";

            echo "<table>";

            echo "<tr> <td> <input type = \"radio\" name = \"ans\" value = \"".$answer0."\"></td> <td>".$answer0."</td> </tr>";
            echo "<tr> <td> <input type = \"radio\" name = \"ans\" value = \"".$answer1."\"></td> <td>".$answer1."</td> </tr>";
            echo "<tr> <td> <input type = \"radio\" name = \"ans\" value = \"".$answer2."\"></td> <td>".$answer2."</td> </tr>";
            echo "<tr> <td> <input type = \"radio\" name = \"ans\" value = \"".$answer3."\"></td> <td>".$answer3."</td> </tr>";

            echo "</table>";

            echo "<input type = \"submit\" name = \"submit1\">";
            echo "<input type = \"submit\" name = \"refresh\">";

            echo "</form>";

            echo "You submitted: ";



            echo "<br><br><br>";
            echo "my xml file: ";


                if (isset($_GET['submit1'])){

                $_SESSION['quizno']++;

                if ($correctans == $_GET['ans']){ 

                    echo "Correct Answer!";
                    $_SESSION['qcorrect']++;


                }else{
                    echo "The wrong answer, try again!";

                }

                }

                if (isset($_GET['refresh'])){
                    $_SESSION['qcorrect'] = 0;
                     $_SESSION['quizno'] = 0;
                }









        ?>  



        </div>
    </body>

</html>




 XML file:

    <?xml version = "1.0"?>
    <quiz>
    <question>
        <ask>What is the name of the movie that this meme comes from?</ask>
        <correctanswer>Downfall</correctanswer>
        <picture>question1.jpg</picture>
        <answers>
            <answer>
                <text>Stalingrad</text>
            </answer>

            <answer>
                <text>Downfall</text>
            </answer>

            <answer>
                <text>Band of Brothers</text>
            </answer>

            <answer>
                <text>The Fuhrer</text>

            </answer>
        </answers>
    </question>

    <question>
        <ask>What is the name of this actor?</ask>
        <correctanswer>Bruno Ganz</correctanswer>
        <picture>question1.jpg</picture>
        <answers>
            <answer>
                <text>Bruno Ganz</text>
            </answer>
            <answer>
                <text>Ulrich Matthes</text>
            </answer>
            <answer>
                <text>Thomas Kretschmann</text>
            </answer>
            <answer>
                <text>Hans Funck</text>
            </answer>
        </answers>

    </question>

    <question>
        <ask>What is the name of the youtube account in which this first appeared in?</ask>
        <picture>questionn2.jpg</picture>
        <correctanswer>wzr0713</correctanswer>
        <answers>
        <answer>
            <text>wzr0713</text>
        </answer>
        <answer>
            <text>rerer434</text>
        </answer>
        <answer>
            <text>karetoshare</text>
        </answer>
        <answer>
            <text>blueberrypie573</text>
        </answer>

        </answers>

    </question>

    <question>
        <ask>What date did this picture first appear on the internet?</ask>
        <picture>questionn2.jpg</picture>
        <correctanswer>June 6 2012</correctanswer>
        <answers>
            <answer>
                <text>Aug 12 2011</text>
            </answer>
            <answer>
                <text>Oct 22 2010</text>
            </answer>
            <answer>
                <text>Aug 13 2011</text>
            </answer>
            <answer>
                <text>June 6 2012</text>
            </answer>
        </answers>
    </question>

    <question>
        <ask>This is a stock photo from which company?</ask>
        <correctanswer>Corbis Images</correctanswer>
        <picture>question3.png</picture>

        <answers>
            <answer>
                <text>Foter</text>
            </answer>
            <answer>
                <text>Getty Images</text>
            </answer>
            <answer>
                <text>Sipa Press</text>
            </answer>
            <answer>
                <text>Corbis Images</text>
            </answer>
        </answers>
    </question>

    <question>
        <ask>Which website did this meme originate from?</ask>
        <correctanswer>quickmeme</correctanswer>
        <picture>question3.png</picture>
        <answers>
            <answer>
                <text>memebase</text>
            </answer>
            <answer>
                <text>funnyjunk</text>
            </answer>
            <answer>
                <text>4chan</text>
            </answer>
            <answer>
                <text>quickmeme</text>
            </answer>
        </answers>
    </question>

    <question>
        <ask>What is the name of the comedy show in which this image first appeared?</ask>
        <correctanswer>Panic Face King</correctanswer>
        <picture>question4.jpeg</picture>
        <answers>
            <answer>
                <text>Takeshi Castle</text>
            </answer>
            <answer>
                <text>Panic Face King</text>
            </answer>
            <answer>
                <text>Spank the laugh</text>
            </answer>
            <answer>
                <text>The Big Moment</text>
            </answer>
        </answers>
    </question>

    <question>
        <ask>What is the name of the person above?</ask>
        <correctanswer>Ayumu Kato</correctanswer>
        <picture>question4.jpeg</picture>
        <answers>
            <answer>
                <text>Katashi Samosoro</text>
            </answer>
            <answer>
                <text>Konno Miko</text>
            </answer>
            <answer>
                <text>Ayumu Kato</text>
            </answer>
            <answer>
                <text>Nakamura Asuka</text>
            </answer>
        </answers>
    </question>


</quiz>
```

Comment: What is it you think `$_SESSION['qcorrect']; $_SESSION['quizno'];` is doing? Because what it's actually doing is nothing.

Comment: Isnt that where you create the session variables? I want to create some variables that can be carried over when the user refreshes the page. Should i store this in a cookie instead?

Comment: You'd create new indicies in the `$_SESSION` array by assigning values to them, not by *stating* them. If this worked the way you think it does and just stating `$_SESSION['quizno'];` somehow *defined* that index within `$_SESSIONS`, your `if (!isset($_SESSION['quizno']))` test would never work.

Comment: Alright. I see. I deleted those 2 lines. The problem is that whenever i click the submit button, it takes the value that i put into my radio button and compares it to the Next question instead of the current question.

Comment: You increment `quizno` regardless of whether question was correct or not, meaning every time you submit the form, you'll get the next question anyways.

Comment: Yeah i see the problem. Do you have any good resources regarding how php, html, javascript, ajax, and all these technologies interleave together to make a website? Like what is the role of PHP compared to Javascript or html? Im not sure if im using php the correct way.

Comment: Also when i load the page i have to submit my answer twice to get the quiz to iterate the questions.

Comment: Should i process quiz answers before outputting html or is it fine as it is?

Comment: PHP is meant to process cookies, read and write databases, and do other server side stuff hidden to the client. PHP executes before the HTML is sent to the client, so it is able to change content before the page loads. Yes, you are doing the right thing with PHP. You want the answer processing to be PHP, not javascript, so it is hidden to the client. JavaScript, on the other hand, is meant to process things on the client side after the page has loaded like animations, button clicks, or any other things the user is supposed to see immediately.